# Using Javascript Regular Expression replace() to remove class

Tags: javascript

If HTML element has more classes for example:

class="red blue white"

I have function that checks if an element has class using Reg Exp test() method and function that eventually adds a class.

Below is the function that removes the class and everything works fine, it is just that I don't understand why the literal expression / $/ in the last line is not same as " $".

" $" will work fine as substitute for / $/ if I remove any other but last class name. In case of removing the last class it remains the white space before closing quotations of the class attribute.

Here is the function:

```
var removeClass  = function(targetById, theClass)
        {
            var pattern = new RegExp("(^| )"+ theClass + "( |$)");

            if(hasClass(targetById, theClass))
            {
                targetById.className = targetById.className.replace(pattern, "$1");
                targetById.className = targetById.className.replace(/ $/, "");
            }
        };


        var heading = document.getElementById("heading");
        removeClass(heading, "white");
```

Comment: Just an aside, there is a ; missing after the closing } of the function expression assigned to "removeClass" :-) Would have been okay in a function declaration... no it doesn't lead to errors (in this case).

Comment: `...replace(/ $/, "");` ***<- this bit?***  Not entirely clear where you're fuzzy but `/ $/` is a regular expression that matches a single white space at the end of a string where as `" $"` is ***not*** a RegExp and will simply replace every occurrence of a space followed by literal dollar sign (of which none would/should exist in a class attribute).

Comment: I understand, if I declared: var spaceLeft = new RegExp(" $"); and then use spaceLeft as searchvalue argument in replace(), that would also work. I fixed ; too :). Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Correct, though you don't need to use the constructor other than when you are creating a dynamic expression (like in your first case).  The literal `/.../` notation is cleaner and concise and tends to be better for performance.  [There's some good reading over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) =)